# How to re-initialize optimization in Python Gekko from prior solution

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

I'm solving a non-linear optimization problem with Gekko in a loop and want to use the prior solution to initialize the next solution. I've created a simplified the problem with the code below to show the issue.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO() # Initialize gekko
# Initialize variables
x1 = m.Var(value=1,lb=1,ub=5)
x2 = m.Var(value=5,lb=1,ub=5)
# Equations
m.Equation(x1==x2*2)
m.Equation(x1**2+x2**2==10)
m.Obj(x1*x2) # Objective
m.options.solver=1

m.solve(disp=False) # Solve
print('Iterations: ' + str(m.options.iterations))
print(x1.value[0], x2.value[0])
print('Objective: ' + str(m.options.objfcnval))

m.solve(disp=False) # Solve again
print('Iterations: ' + str(m.options.iterations))
print(x1.value[0], x2.value[0])
print('Objective: ' + str(m.options.objfcnval))
```

The console prints:

```
  Iterations: 5
  2.8284271334 1.4142135667
  Objective: 4.0000000245
  Iterations: 5
  2.8284271334 1.4142135667
  Objective: 4.0000000245
```

The values of `x1` and `x2` return to the initial guesses of 1 and 5 before the "Solve again" attempt. I tried `x1.value = x1.value` but this returns `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`. What is the right way to initialize values from a prior solution in Gekko?

Answer (score 2):

For steady state solutions (IMODE=1 or 3), Gekko uses the prior `x1.value` and `x2.value` until they are changed. The `.value` has two properties: `.value` and `.change`. There are multiple ways to signal that they have changed including:

1. Set the values from the prior solution with:

```py
x1.value = x1.value.value  # = 2.8284271334
x2.value = x2.value.value  # = 1.4142135667
```

2. Signal that the initial guess value should change to the new value with:

```py
x1.value.change = True
x2.value.change = True
```

This is easy with two variables but it is more challenging with many variables. If you want to automate this for all of your variables, you could use the built-in list of variables in a loop with `vi in m._variables`:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO() # Initialize gekko
# Initialize variables
x1 = m.Var(value=1,lb=1,ub=5)
x2 = m.Var(value=5,lb=1,ub=5)
# Equations
m.Equation(x1==x2*2)
m.Equation(x1**2+x2**2==10)
m.Obj(x1*x2) # Objective
m.options.solver=1

m.solve(disp=False) # Solve
print('Iterations: ' + str(m.options.iterations))
print(x1.value[0], x2.value[0])
print('Objective: ' + str(m.options.objfcnval))

for vi in m._variables:
    vi.value.change = True

m.solve(disp=False) # Solve again
print('Iterations: ' + str(m.options.iterations))
print(x1.value[0], x2.value[0])
print('Objective: ' + str(m.options.objfcnval))
```

The second time it solves the problem, the solver finishes in 1 iteration instead of 5 iterations. It is using the prior solution as the starting point.

```
  Iterations: 5
  2.8284271334 1.4142135667
  Objective: 4.0000000245
  Iterations: 1
  2.8284271247 1.4142135624
  Objective: 4.0
```